# Ansible2.4 playbook Variable precedence when using import_playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to reuse generic playbooks so that they can be played within any larger scenario.

Think a build-basic-server playbook (which is composed of roles) that can be run on different cloud provider while overriding the generic playbook variables.

```
group_vars/
  all
playbooks/
  build-basic-server/
    group_vars/
      all
    roles/
      firewall/
      web/
      ...
    build.yml 
roles/
  my-cloud-provider/ or container/
main.yml (with - import_playbook: playbooks/build-basic-server/build.yml)
```

This works well, but my trouble is that I can't rely on the main `group_vars/all` to take precedence over the `playbooks/build-basic-server/group_vars/all`.

I need the main `group_vars/all` to override the playbook one so that I can keep the playbook generic and testable with test variables values (Otherwise I'd have to a specific  branch of the playbook per usage and would need to merge any modification to each branch...).

Is there any way to make this main `group_vars/all` take precedence over everything? 
Do you have any other way to implement such a use case?

Answer (score 1):

Using this additional folder for variables

```
inventory/
  group_vars/
    all
```

does override values in

```
playbooks/
  build-basic-server/
    group_vars/
      all
```

for

```
playbooks/
  build-basic-server/
    build.xml
```

but not for root

```
main.yml
```

This is equivalent to switching from Play to Host [Variable Scope](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes)

So that's one possible solution to the stated problem.